# htaccess friendly url not working redirect to 404 page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with friendly URL. I have registration on my website and user is getting code to his email, then he has to click on the link:

```
https://example.com/activate/f37296ae70cd0df88e959cfd13e23738
```

This is what it looks like before the change:

```
https://example.com/activate.php?c=f37296ae70cd0df88e959cfd13e23738
```

This code redirect to 404 page.

```
RewriteRule ^activate/(.*)$ activate.php?c=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Can you help me with that?
Thank you.

Comment: What is serving the 404 response? Your script or Apache? What other directives do you have in the `.htaccess` file? The rule you've posted is "OK" by itself.