# issues with .htaccess rewrite rules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Having issues with `.htaccess` rewrite rules. Passing a URL to the browser from users email that includes a token for password reset.

Current `.htaccess` rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.DOMAIN\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://DOMIAN.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(?:GET|POST)\ /.*\.php\ HTTP.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

when user trying to go to

`example.com/activate/00803e6632236414ebcdc34c7e7690d764e567083fac6`

produces these errors in debug

`example.com/activate/00803e6632236414ebcdc34c7e7690d764e567083fac6.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php`

So I update .htaccess per your notes below like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.EXAMPLE\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://EXAMPLE.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(?:GET|POST)\ /.*\.php\ HTTP.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite extensionless ".php" URLs
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule (.+) $1.php [L]

# Rewrite "/<file>/<code>" to "/<file>.php/<code>"
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([a-f0-9])$ $1.php/$2 [L]
```

And I get the following error:

> AH00128: File does not exist: /var/www/html/htdocs/activate/00803e6632236414ebcdc34c7e7690d764e567083fac6

Comment: Yes, the above code would result in the erroneous output you are seeing. But what should happen to such a request? How are you expecting this to be handled/routed? It would seem `activate.php` exists? (Hhmm, looks a bit similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76953875/htaccess-friendly-url-not-working-redirect-to-404-page)?)

Comment: It is suppose to treat activate as activate.php. The rules work for my other pages without error, but when appending a user token it is rewriting .php in a loop to the end of the token instead of treating activate as activate.php

Comment: So, it should be rewritten to `/activate.php/<code>` (where `/<code>` is passed as path-info to the `activate.php` script)? Presumably your "other pages" aren't called quite like that?

Comment: Correct. I am just having issues figuring the correct syntax for that without affect my other pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
> ```

The problem with this rule is that you are checking one filesystem path (ie. `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php`) and rewriting to another (`$1.php`). These do not necessarily refer to the same thing. For a request to `/activate/foo`, where `activate` is not a filesystem directory then `REQUEST_FILENAME` is of the form `/var/www/html/htdocs/activate` (so the file check is successful since `/var/www/html/htdocs/activate.php` exists), but it rewrites the request to `activate/foo.php` (using the `$1` backreference) - which does not exist. It will do this repeatedly, appending `.php` each time (until it reaches an internal rewrite limit; default 10).

*Aside#1:* There is no need to check that the request does not map to a directory and does not map to a file before checking that the request+`.php` does map to a file. That's 3 (expensive) filesystem checks when only one is required.

*Aside#2:* You also don't need to backslash escape the literal dot in the *TestString* (first argument), since this is an "ordinary" string, not a regex.

This rule needs to be corrected, so that you are testing the same file-path that you are ultimately rewriting to. For example:

```
# Rewrite extensionless ".php" URLs
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule (.+) $1.php [L]
```

You then need an additional rule to rewrite the request `/activate/<code>` to `/activate.php/<code>` (passing `/<code>` to your script as path-info). This could be "hardcoded" if this is a one-off. For example:

```
# Rewrite "/activate/<code>" to "/activate.php/<code>"
RewriteRule ^(activate)/([a-f0-9]+)$ $1.php/$2 [L]
```

(I'm assuming `<code>` is a hexadecimal sequence, which appears to be the case in your example.)

Or make it more generic, if you have similar requests. eg. `/<file>/<code>` to `/<file>.php/<code>`. For example:

```
# Rewrite "/<file>/<code>" to "/<file>.php/<code>"
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([a-f0-9]+)$ $1.php/$2 [L]
```

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(?:GET|POST)\ /.*\.php\ HTTP.*$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]
> ```

This rule (external redirect) should be *before* the above rewrites.

Comment: Edited the above to show my corrections and the error I am still getting

Comment: @nw_prod Presumably if you were to request `/activate.php/00803e6632236414ebcdc34c7e7690d764e567083fac6` directly you get the expected response? (I assume `RewriteEngine OnRewriteBase /` is on two lines?)

Comment: Correct. If i manually add .php after activate like activate.php/<code> it pulls the correct page

Comment: @nw_prod Sorry, I missed the quantifier (`+`) in the second part of the regex! It should be `^([^/]+)/([a-f0-9]+)$` (not `^([^/]+)/([a-f0-9])$`)! So it would only have matched a code that consisted of a single character, not a 45-char string! I've updated my answer. If the "codes" are always 45 characters (as in your example) then you could restrict the regex to exactly that. eg. `[a-f0-9]{45}`

Comment: That did the trick.  Working correctly now.  Thank you very much for your help and guidance.

Comment: i have one last question,  I am getting on last error on this page where a page requirement is adding the "activate" as part of directory structure.  See here.
    AH00128: File does not exist: /var/www/html/htdocs/activate/js/plugin/bootstrap-colorpicker/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css

Comment: actually that didn't fix the issue

Comment: @nw_prod "a page requirement is adding the "activate" as part of directory structure" - what do you mean by that? (By "requirement" do you mean "resource" or "asset"?) Is that intentional? Do you have an `/activate` subdirectory? So _that_ is a valid URL-path? Or not?

Comment: No it is an asset it the page is trying to call. There is no activate directory. It should be htdocs/js but instead it is adding activate in the middle "htdocs/activate/js"

Comment: @nw_prod I'm guessing you are perhaps (erroneously) using a _relative_ URL-path to access this asset? eg. something like `href="js/plugin/bootstrap-colorpicker/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css"`? This is then resolved (by the browser) relative to the current URL (eg. `/activate/00803...`) which naturally results in `/activate/js/plugin/etc.` instead of the intended `/js/plugin/etc.`. You need to use root-relative URLs to your static assets. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43737411/404-not-found-broken-links-to-css-images

Comment: @nw_prod This is not an issue with the `.htaccess` file per se, but the fact that you are accessing your page from differing path depths (when it is "expecting" to be accessed from the root).